# ASP.NET Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk hangs on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk-net

**Environment**:

1. Windows 10 home edition(upgraded from Windows 8)
2. Visual Studio 2017 with [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2107](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/preview-of-the-aws-toolkit-for-visual-studio-2017/) installed

I'm using this [AWS Official Tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-beanstalk-netcore.html) to deploy a very simple ASP.NET Core 1.1 app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. But the installation hangs at two places shown in red in the image below. I'm using the user in a group that has the following **permissions** in AWS: `SystemAdministrator`, `AmazonEC2FullAccess`, `AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess`

**Snapshot of Deployment to AWS Status in Visual Studio** [**Note**: clicking on a picture will maximize the picture for a better view]:
[image]

Following is a snapshot of **AWS Explorer in VS2017** and Status View of Elastic BeanStalk instance on the Left side:

[image]

**UPDATE**

After reading comments from `@MattHouser` I went to AWS console panel and opened my `Elastic Beanstalk` console to notice that, indeed, the app has been deployed there successfully as shown in the console snapshots below. But when I click on the app's URL I still get the error: `HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure`. **Question**: What I need to do to make URL work? **NOTE**: The web app is a very simple ASP.NET Core app created from this ASP.NET's [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db). App runs fine locally on VS2017 using built-in IISExpress. And, although the local copy of the app is using small SQL Express db but the local app's home page is not using db and opens fine even if I stop the SQL Express Services on my local machine.

**Elastic Beanstalk snaphots on my AWS account:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: @MattHouser The first image above is the status window of the AWS Publisher wizard. It completes several steps shown in the image except the two shown in red. I waited for hours and refreshed but the two steps in red are still there. I then tried testing - just in case - by clicking on the URL shown on top of the image and it just gives the HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure error that I think is probably not relevant here since the process hanged on EC2

Comment: They did finish. The line at 3/21/2017 5:19:00 says "Successfully launched environment: ...". So it's launched. Elastic Beanstalk has completed it's work. The 502.5 errors you are seeing are due to issues in your web app.

Comment: And at 3/21/2017 8:05:42 "New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances". Your issue is not Elastic Beanstalk. It's something else.

Comment: @MattHouser Your guess seems to be correct. After reading your observations, I've just added an **UPDATE** section with a question.

Comment: Do you have a health check URL for your EB application? Is that URL working and returning 200? When you get the `HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure` error, what else does it say? Can you include a screenshot of that?

Comment: @MattHouser The screenshot for the  error is exactly the same as shown on [this](https://stackify.com/net-core-azure-app-service-wont-start/) and [this](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/252) posts. The users there seem to have had same issue on `Azure`. In my EB console, I do not see health check URL. How do I find it?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but try the following: (a) try pulling the logs from your EC2 instance, this is done from the Logs nav link in the EB console, (b) follow the logging steps mentioned in that article you linked, you'll need to RDP into your Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances to do that.